# The out parameter does not work in C#. Why?

Tags: c#, syntax, syntax-error, out

The `out` parameter does not work in C#. Why?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(2);
        Console.WriteLine(hashSet.Contains(2));
    }
    
    public ListNode ReverseList(ListNode head) 
    {
        helper(head, out var newHead);
        return newHead;
    }
    
    private ListNode helper(ListNode current, out ListNode newHead) 
    {
        newHead = null;
        
        if (current == null) 
        {
            return null;
        }
        
        var next = helper(current.next, out newHead);

        if (next == null) 
        {
            newHead = current;
        } 
        else 
        {
            next.next = current;
        }
        
        return current;
    }
}

public class ListNode 
{
    public int val;
    public ListNode next;

    public ListNode(int val = 0, ListNode next = null) 
    {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> Compilation error (line 13, col 30): ) expected
> Compilation error (line 13, col 37): ; expected
> Compilation error (line 13, col 37): Invalid expression term ')'

I have spent 2 hours straight trying to figure out what is wrong. Help me, please.

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qM4JAz) is my code online.

Comment: Declare `newHead` before using it as an `out` parameter, and remove the `var` keyword.

Comment: @MichaelMyers, does not work. It tells me that `A local variable or function named 'newHead' is already defined in this scope`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your sample at dotnet fiddle and it seems like the compiler (version) matters. I got the same exception when running your code on the .NET 4.7.2 compiler, but when you change the compiler to Roslyn 3.8 or .NET 5 the sample works.

Answer (score 0):

Change line 13

```
helper(head, out var newHead);
```

to

```
var newHead = new ListNode();
helper(head, out newHead);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you're in the wrong Visual Studio version, even if the framework version is correct.  Note that double-clicking the solution (.sln) file doesn't always result in the project opening in the desired VS version.  If you have multiple VS versions installed, first launch the one you want and then open the solution using the File menu.